# Why IN OUT parameter returning value without registering for callable statement?

Tags: java, oracle

I am invoking pk_adduser.pr_checkuser() from java using CallableStatement which contains two IN parameters and one IN OUT parameter. I have not registered IN OUT parameter using CallableStatement.registerOutParameter(int parameterIndex, int sqlType).
But still i am able to get the output value using IN OUT parameter if the returning value length is same as input value length else i am getting SQL exception like ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error.

I am using Java 1.7 and Oracle 12c.

My package like below:
I have used the p_user_login_id parameter but not included in given code, just given piece of code.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY pk_adduser
AS
PROCEDURE pr_checkuser (
      p_first_name          IN       VARCHAR,
      p_last_name           IN       VARCHAR,
      p_user_login_id       IN OUT   VARCHAR);

/

PROCEDURE pr_checkuser (
      p_first_name          IN       VARCHAR,
      p_last_name           IN       VARCHAR,
      p_user_login_id       IN OUT   VARCHAR)
IS

BEGIN
    SELECT user_login_id
    INTO p_user_login_id
    FROM user_account
    WHERE first_name = p_first_name
    AND last_name    = p_last_name;
END pr_checkuser;
END;
```

My Java code like below:

```
String getcall = "{call pk_adduser.pr_checkuser (?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement callsts = connect.prepareCall(getcall);
callsts.setString(1, "Ramesh");
callsts.setString(2, "Nuvvula");
callsts.setString(3, "RamN");
callsts.execute();
String user_id = callsts.getString(3);
System.out.println("user_id: "+user_id);
```

p_user_login_id='RamN' i am passing to IN OUT parameter, select query returns 'RameshN' which is available in Data base and trying to assign to p_user_login_id.

If i pass p_user_login_id='RamN123' its returning 'RameshN' successfully.

I think Passing parameter value's length is the Issue. But my question how can it behave like this ?

Comment: Why declare `p_user_login_id` as `IN` parameter if you do nothing with the value inside your procedure?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have used the p_user_login_id   parameter but not included in given code, just given piece of code.

Comment: Then please show the actual relevant code

Comment: What JDK are you using? Is it Oracle's? What JDBC driver are you using? Is it Oracle's? If you are using Oracle JDK and JDBC driver, then you need to match JDK version to JDBC driver version to Oracle database version. The [Oracle JDBC FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02) has information on what versions are compatible. You can also refer to [JDBC Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/title.htm) for Oracle 12c. My guess is either you have uncovered an Oracle bug or you are using an incompatible combination.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild guess here, but try this:

```
String result = "RamN";
String getcall = "{call pk_adduser.pr_checkuser (?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement callsts = connect.prepareCall(getcall);
callsts.setString(1, "Ramesh");
callsts.setString(2, "Nuvvula");
callsts.setString(3,  result);
callsts.execute();
String user_id = callsts.getString(3);
```

However, the pl/sql code does not make sense to pass in an in/out parameter whose in value is never used.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have used the pass in IN/OUT parameter but not included in given code, just given piece of code.  I have tried what have suggested but still not working..